# Table View Controller delegate is nil, but should be a valid reference

Tags: ios, xcode, delegates, uitableview

I'm designing a simple Grocery List app, but having trouble adding a Food entity to a List entity.

Sequence of events: ListDetailTVC -> AddFoodToListTVC -> type in food name -> save

at this point I want to see this food in the list, but instead nothing happens. The screen stays the same. After some delving into I realized the delegate was nil in AddFoodToListTVC, so there was no screen to return to after 'save' was pressed.

Then I tried manually setting the delegate with the following code:

```
`if(delegate == nil)

   {
        self.delegate = (ListDetailTVC *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    }


NSLog(@"delegate = %@", delegate);
`
```

This sets the AddFoodToListTVC delegate to something, but I'm not sure how to verify Im setting it correctly. When I run my app with the above addition, I get this error when I click save.

"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate theSaveButtonOnTheAddFoodToListTVCWasTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b56610' "

0x6b56610 in this case is the address of the delegate I am manually setting.

I know that's not much info, but I can supply any relevant code. Im at my wits end, how do I set the delegate for AddFoodToListTVC correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your app delegate does not implement this method: theSaveButtonOnTheAddFoodToListTVCWasTapped:

Answer (score 0):

Delegates are something like **event triggers** which are received by **delegated object**... like **rowWasSelected** is an event which needs to be handled by someone for the mandatory methods....

Now the thing is ur setting **AppDelegate** as the receiver object for delegates **[self.delegate = (ListDetailTVC *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];]**...

But as AppDelegate doesnt handle those events, you get an exception **[unrecognized selector]**...

So first thing is declare protocol i.e., **UITableViewDelegate**, **UITableViewDataSource**... [protocols are like interface which has only declaraion not implementation, you need to provide implementation]  Set tableViews **DataSource** and **Delegate** and implement those protocols. Will solve your problem